# NSMutableArray release crashes my program -- why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I thought I understood memory management well enough until this issue happened (Mac OS X 10.6): I have a custom NSView subclass with an NSMutableArray instance variable, but when I dealloc my view and attempt to release that instance variable, *sometimes* BOOM, EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens.  This happens when I try to close my document window without quitting the program, but for some reason, even under identical conditions, sometimes it works without issue.  Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?  The relevant bits of code from my NSView subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        rainbow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            // some objects go here, followed by the nil sentinel
            ]
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

And the dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"Release the rainbow!");
    if (rainbow) {
        [rainbow removeAllObjects]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here
        [rainbow release];
    }
}
```

Even though I check whether rainbow is still around, sending it a message results in that segfault.  There is one spot where it gets used: it's passed as a *info argument to a CGShading callback function.  Here are the relevant bits of that function (which generally works without crashing):

```
NSMutableArray *colorStops = (NSMutableArray *)info;
[colorStops retain];
/*
    ...
*/
[colorStops release];
```

I'm guessing that there's something here about threads, but I really don't know.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thank you very much!  I've reread the memory management guide; any more headdesking on this and my glass tabletop shatters in my face.

Answer (score 3):

Always do

```
[super dealloc]
```

at the end of your dealloc method.

Comment: and there is no need to release the objects, they will automatically be removed from the array and released when the array is released.

Comment: ...Well THAT worked. (:  Thank you!  I hadn't considered that the order of deallocs there would affect the instance variables of the subclass.  And to timthetoolman, that line was only there because I had originally thought that the dealloc issue was with the objects in the array; thanks for noticing it.  I've just removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Terry's point about `[super dealloc]`, the `-removeAllObjects` call will message all of the objects in the array (to release them). If you have overreleased any of those objects, the pointer that the array has may now point to deallocated or otherwise invalid space.

So, you have to review your memory management of all of the objects in the array. Run your app under the Zombies instrument. Do a Build and Analyze and resolve the identified issues.